# Recursive calls between two functions

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, functional-programming

I need to recursive check two objects and keys need to be sorted, so I created two functions.

*buildObj* - get all uniq keys from object, sort them and call *buildObjKey* on each key

*buildObjKey* - if one of values is object call *buildObj* for these. Other returns is example and real code is more complex.

So question: I define  *buildObj* before *buildObjKey* and call buildObjKey while its not defined yet. This is bad practice, but if I move definition of *buildObj* after *buildObjKey* I will call *buildObj* before It was defined... This is possible to do recursive calls between two functions without this trouble?

```
const _ = require('lodash')

const example1 = {
  key3: 'foo',
  key1: {
    key4: {
      key6: 'boo'
    },
  },
}

const example2 = {
  key3: 'too',
  key1: {
    key4: {
      key6: 'hoo'
    },
  },
}

const buildObj = (obj1, obj2) => {
 return  _.uniq([...Object.keys(obj1), ...Object.keys(obj2)])
 .sort()
 .map(key => buildObjKey(key, obj1, obj2))
}

const buildObjKey = (key, obj1, obj2) => {
  const val1 = obj1[key];
  const val2 = obj2[key];
  if(val1 && val2){
    if(_.isObject(val1) && _.isObject(val2)){
      return buildObj(val1, val2)
    }
    if(_.isObject(val1)){
      return buildObj(val1, val1)
    }
    if(_.isObject(val2)){
      return buildObj(val2, val2)
    }
    return val1
  }
  return val1 || val2
}

buildObj(example1, example2)
```

[image]

Execution example
[ [ [ 'boo' ] ], 'foo' ]

The real code is doing diff of two object, i don't write it here because of complexity. Here is simple example of structure.

Comment: Have you considered using currying? Have you maybe considered wrapping these methods in a static class? Or have you considered something like hoisting? etc.

Comment: What does this code? What is the definition of expected behaviour? Right now it returns `[[["boo"]], "foo"]` and there are plenty of ways to get it like this. If you explain the logic maybe we can help you.

Comment: This is super-confusing. The code itself has nothing to do with the problem. The problem can be summarized in this code:
`
function aaa() {
 bbb()
}

function bbb () {
 aaa()
}
`
And we DO want to use `bbb` before it's defined. So you could just suppress the linter warning.

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define

Comment: This shouldn't be an error. ESLint is not smart enough in this case. Do yourself a favor and use TypeScript checker instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a number of ways you can get around this problem & I'd honestly say that it may depend on what you consider important, i.e. it may depend on your style of coding & what preferences you have.

---

## Hoisting

A simple enough technique to use, feel free to read up more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), but in a *nutshell* hoisting is where you declare a variable towards the start of the file, then use it at some later point. But with functions specifically all you *need* to do to make use of this concept is define them as traditional functions. The idea being that when you define a function **using** the keyword `function`, the function *essentially* gets defined before other variables within the scope.

Here's a little example:

```js
test();

function test() {
  console.log("Hello! :)")
}
```

---

## Currying

Personally I'm a big fan of currying, I think it's pretty damn great to be honest with you, so much so that I've even [written](https://dev.to/jo3w3bd3v/currying-with-react-15k6) about how currying works great with React. If you're unsure of what currying is, it's *essentially* where you have one method that accepts one argument & returns a result or a function that also takes one argument & so on. If you're new to this concept, maybe read through the likes of [this post](https://javascript.info/currying-partials), I won't go on & on about it because I know that other people will do a better job of explaining it than I will! But that aside, you *could* essentially achieve something like this:

```js
const fn1 = (arg) => (callback) => {
  if (callback === undefined || callback === null) {
    console.log(arg);
  } else if (typeof callback === "function") {
    callback(arg);
  } else {
    throw new Error("The callback argument must be defined, fn1(arg)(callback).");
  }
}

const fn2 = (arg) => {
  if (arg === "test") {
    fn1(arg)(() => {
      console.log(`This is a ${arg}`);
    });
  } else {
    fn1(arg)();
  }
};

fn2(5);
fn2("test");
```

I mean you *could* even use a more tried & tested method & make use of a call-back function without the currying if you so desired, i.e. you could pass in an object that contains an array of keys. Then based on what keys are present in the provided arguments, you *could* very easily do it that way if you desired.

---

## Class Syntax

This is another simple way, where all of your functions are defined *within* a class, you could *essentially* make the class static/stateless if you desire, I mean it's a bit of a context specific subject matter I think, not to mention your coding style(s) & ideas. But anyway, you don't have to worry about the order in which you write your code or anything like that, you can just do something straight up simple & easy to maintain, like so:

```js
class Test {
  run () {
    this.print();
  }

  print() {
    console.log("I ran!");
  }
}

new Test().run();
```

I mean this approach would make a bit more sense if you're using TypeScript as you can define `print` as a private method, thus you'd *only* be able to call the `run` method outside of the class, but I'm confident that you get the idea?

---

## Conclusion

I think that it depends on your ESLint configuration also, but more importantly your style of coding & what you or your team value the most, I think it's reasonable to state that there are many ways you could solve this problem, it's just a matter of deciding what suits your needs best.

If anyone has anything to add, feel free to edit my answer or add a comment, but I think this is one of those matters where there's no one correct answer? Feel free to disagree! **P.S.** As you've tagged this question with `functional-programming`, I'd suggest you make use of currying, I for one love it!

Comment: your post starts with the premise _"So there are a number of ways you can get around this problem"_ but there is no problem. `buildObj` does not actually call `buildObjKey` before it is defined. the OP has written a completely valid pair of [mutually recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) functions.

Comment: @Thankyou fair point, but I thought I'd give my 2￠, I agree it's not a problem strictly speaking, but I just found _maybe_ the OP wanted to explore potentially different ways of essentially writing the same solution. I.E. It could be that it goes against his companies coding style guidelines? - I don't know enough information to state if this is the case or not, I doubt it, but I don't officially know.

Answer (score 4):

**misunderstanding**

> I define `buildObj` before `buildObjKey` and call `buildObjKey` while its not defined yet... This is bad practice, but if I move definition of `buildObj` after `buildObjKey` I will call `buildObj` before It was defined...

That's untrue. `buildObj` is a **function** and it is not called before you define `buildObjKey`. The fact that `buildObj` contains a reference to `buildObjKey` does not mean that it tries to immediately call it. To demonstrate this concretely, let's see a simplified example below.

Notice how `isEven` and `isOdd` do not produce output *until* one of the functions is actually called -

```js
function isEven (n)
{ console.log("isEven", n)
  if (n == 0)
    return true
  else
    return isOdd(n - 1)   // <- calls isOdd
}

function isOdd (n)
{ console.log("isOdd", n)
  if (n == 0)
    return false
  else
    return isEven(n - 1)  // <- calls isEven
}

console.log("first line of output")

console.log("result", isOdd(3))
```

```
first line of output
isOdd 3
isEven 2
isOdd 1
isEven 0
result true
```

---

**possible and powerful**

> This is possible to do recursive calls between two functions without this trouble?

This is a massively powerful technique known as [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion). Mutual recursion is an excellent way to process recursive trees like the deeply-nested objects you have in your program. You have good intuition to process them this way. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55144491/633183) for a practical example and explanation.

---

**related**

Coincidentally I wrote a generic object diffing function in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33233053/633183). This demonstrates the strength of generic functions and reusable code. Using the `test1` and `test2` inputs from your question, we can calculate a precise diff without any modification to the original code -

```js
const test1 = {
  "common": {
    "setting1": "Value 1",
    "setting2": 200,
    "setting3": true,
    "setting6": {
      "key": "value",
      "doge": {
        "wow": ""
      }
    }
  },
  "group1": {
    "baz": "bas",
    "foo": "bar",
    "nest": {
      "key": "value"
    }
  },
  "group2": {
    "abc": 12345,
    "deep": {
      "id": 45
    }
  }
}
```

```js
const test2 = {
  "common": {
    "follow": false,
    "setting1": "Value 1",
    "setting3": null,
    "setting4": "blah blah",
    "setting5": {
      "key5": "value5"
    },
    "setting6": {
      "key": "value",
      "ops": "vops",
      "doge": {
        "wow": "so much"
      }
    }
  },
  "group1": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": "bars",
    "nest": "str"
  },
  "group3": {
    "fee": 100500,
    "deep": {
      "id": {
        "number": 45
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
console.log(diff(test1, test2))
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results of `diff` in your own browser -

```js
const isObject = x =>
  Object(x) === x

const isArray =
  Array.isArray

const mut = (o, [ k, v ]) =>
  (o[k] = v, o)

const diff1 = (left = {}, right = {}, rel = "left") =>
  Object
    .entries(left)
    .map
      ( ([ k, v ]) =>
          isObject(v) && isObject(right[k])
            ? [ k, diff1(v, right[k], rel) ]
        : right[k] !== v
            ? [ k, { [rel]: v } ]
        : [ k, {} ]
      )
    .filter
      ( ([ _, v ]) =>
          Object.keys(v).length !== 0
      )
    .reduce
      ( mut
      , isArray(left) && isArray(right) ? [] : {}
      )

const merge = (left = {}, right = {}) =>
  Object
    .entries(right)
    .map
      ( ([ k, v ]) =>
          isObject(v) && isObject(left [k])
            ? [ k, merge(left [k], v) ]
            : [ k, v ]
      )
    .reduce(mut, left)


const diff = (x = {}, y = {}, rx = "left", ry = "right") =>
  merge
    ( diff1(x, y, rx)
    , diff1(y, x, ry)
    )

const test1 = {
  "common": {
    "setting1": "Value 1",
    "setting2": 200,
    "setting3": true,
    "setting6": {
      "key": "value",
      "doge": {
        "wow": ""
      }
    }
  },
  "group1": {
    "baz": "bas",
    "foo": "bar",
    "nest": {
      "key": "value"
    }
  },
  "group2": {
    "abc": 12345,
    "deep": {
      "id": 45
    }
  }
}

const test2 = {
  "common": {
    "follow": false,
    "setting1": "Value 1",
    "setting3": null,
    "setting4": "blah blah",
    "setting5": {
      "key5": "value5"
    },
    "setting6": {
      "key": "value",
      "ops": "vops",
      "doge": {
        "wow": "so much"
      }
    }
  },
  "group1": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": "bars",
    "nest": "str"
  },
  "group3": {
    "fee": 100500,
    "deep": {
      "id": {
        "number": 45
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(diff(test1, test2))
```

```js
{
  "common": {
    "setting2": {
      "left": 200
    },
    "setting3": {
      "left": true,
      "right": null
    },
    "setting6": {
      "doge": {
        "wow": {
          "left": "",
          "right": "so much"
        }
      },
      "ops": {
        "right": "vops"
      }
    },
    "follow": {
      "right": false
    },
    "setting4": {
      "right": "blah blah"
    },
    "setting5": {
      "right": {
        "key5": "value5"
      }
    }
  },
  "group1": {
    "baz": {
      "left": "bas",
      "right": "bars"
    },
    "nest": {
      "left": {
        "key": "value"
      },
      "right": "str"
    }
  },
  "group2": {
    "left": {
      "abc": 12345,
      "deep": {
        "id": 45
      }
    }
  },
  "group3": {
    "right": {
      "fee": 100500,
      "deep": {
        "id": {
          "number": 45
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```